# Convergence of recursive sequence $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-1}+1}$ where $0<x_0<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion

as you can see from the title I have a recursive sequence with the type above. I want to prove that this sequence converges. Although I have searched a lot for some related sequence, I haven't figured out how to prove that it is monotonous. Which is the preferred way of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$. The sequence can be written then as $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$.

[image]

On $(0,1)$ we have $x< f(x)<1$. From here it follows easily that $x_n>x_{n-1}$ and $x_n<1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I tried to do something like that but I'm puzzled regarding one thing: Isn't \sqrt{3}/2<f(x)<1 this way?

Comment: Yes, it is true, but the important fact to show that the sequence is increasing is that $x<f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

It should read: $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-1}+1}$ , where $ 0<x_0<1$.

1. Show by induction: $0<x_n <1$ for all $n$.
2. Show by induction: $(x_n)$ is increasing.

Comment: How were you able to see these facts are true? Did you plug in a few numbers?

Comment: @Ovi both are easy to see if you write it down (the point is to know what to look for, that comes with experience. But in this case this is also rather straightforward to figure out, you just ask yourself which theorems could I apply, then check the prerequisites)

Comment: @Ovi: yes I plugged in a few numbers for orientation !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that I have a solution, first of all I showed that $0<x_1<1$ . Since $0<x_0<1$, this means that also $0<x_0^2<1$ and also that $x_0^2<x_0$ <=> $x_0^2-x_0<0$ <=> $x_0^2-x_0+1<1$, which means that $x_1=\sqrt{x_0^2-x_0+1}<1$. So in the same manner I proved that if $0<x_n<1$ then also $0<x_{n+1}<1$. 
After that I showed that $x_{n+1}-x_n>0$, so $x_n$ is increasing until it reaches 1.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't figured out how to prove that it is monotonous

It is given that $0 \lt x_0 \lt 1\,$, and suppose by induction that $0 \lt x_{n-1} \lt 1\,$. Then:

- $$\require{cancel}
  1 - x_n^2 = \cancel{1}-(x_{n-1}^2-x_{n-1}+\cancel{1})=x_{n-1}-x_{n-1}^2=x_{n-1}(1-x_{n-1}) \;\in\; (0,1)
  $$
- $$
   x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}^2-2x_{n-1}+1+ x_{n-1}}=\sqrt{(x_{n-1}-1)^2+x_{n-1}} \gt \sqrt{x_{n-1}} \gt x_{n-1}
  $$

Therefore $0 \lt x_n \lt 1$ and $x_n \gt x_{n-1}\,$, which completes the induction step and proves both monotonicity and boundedness to $(0,1)\,$.